# EditText with multiple lines option accepts enter key as value android

Tags: android-edittext, enter

This might be silly question ever but still couldn't find solution. I have EditText with multiple line option on press of enter key in softkey moves to next lines and when clicked on post button to post the content of edittext the value has 2 enter option[i.e 2 blank lines]. before posting i do check for
blank and null value but this doesn't prevent posting enter value.

```
if (!(story_write_text.getText().toString().equals(""))||!(story_write_text.getText().toString().equals(null)))
```

my question: how to check edittext value if there are only enter values so that i can prevent from posting blank enter value to server.

**here's my edittext xml code:**

```
<EditText
               android:id="@+id/story_write_text"
               style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
               android:gravity="left"
               android:hint="Write a comment"
               android:inputType="textCapSentences"
               android:padding="5dp"
               android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 just add android:inputType="textPersonName" 
    to the EditText it will stop it from pressing enter
```

If it not working then use below code

I would subclass the widget and override the key event handling in order to block the Enter key:

```
class MyTextView extends EditText
{
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) 
        {
            // Just ignore the [Enter] key
            return true;
        }
        // Handle all other keys in the default way
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: its edittext with multiple lines so i do need enter key option but need to cross check whether the entire value in edittext is not just new line character[enter value].